# How does the Python's stack work when dealing with tuples/lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, python-internals, pythoninterpreter

I saw in Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_TUPLE) that the `BUILD_TUPLE` instruction "Creates a tuple consuming count items from the stack, and pushes the resulting tuple onto the stack."

It really pushes the tuple itself? What if the tuple contains a large number of elements? How it is placed on stack?

Answer (score 2):

further to @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer and me playing with the `dis` module for the first time…

it might be instructive to disassemble the trivial function:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
  return (a, b, c)
```

which results in:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              3
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

in other words: we're making sure the stack has the correct parameter values on the top, then pops them all off and replaces them with a (reference to a) single tuple.

this is how [stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine)s traditionally operate, which I believe CPython is (at least partially) modelled after, e.g. [What does it mean that python is stack based?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34149013/1358308)

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to CPython specifically, but *all* CPython objects live on a [private heap](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/memory.html).

> Memory management in Python involves a private heap containing all
>   Python objects and data structures. The management of this private
>   heap is ensured internally by the Python memory manager. The Python
>   memory manager has different components which deal with various
>   dynamic storage management aspects, like sharing, segmentation,
>   preallocation or caching.
>
> At the lowest level, a raw memory allocator ensures that there is
>   enough room in the private heap for storing all Python-related data by
>   interacting with the memory manager of the operating system. On top of
>   the raw memory allocator, several object-specific allocators operate
>   on the same heap and implement distinct memory management policies
>   adapted to the peculiarities of every object type. For example,
>   integer objects are managed differently within the heap than strings,
>   tuples or dictionaries because integers imply different storage
>   requirements and speed/space tradeoffs. The Python memory manager thus
>   delegates some of the work to the object-specific allocators, but
>   ensures that the latter operate within the bounds of the private heap.

Note, *everything* in Python is an object. The only thing going onto the interpreter stack is a PyObject pointer. The stack here being an implementation detail of the CPython runtime. Source code is compiled to bytecode, which is executed on this stack-based virtual machine.